# What event I can tap into that fires before loading wp-admin page?

Tags: wp-admin

I have some code that I need to execute. I am currently executing it in response to the [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) event. This is giving me desired result for pages other than `/wp-admin`. What event can I tap into that fires before wordpress starts processing `/wp-admin`? I need an event that will fire just before `/wp-admin` processing starts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earliest admin related hook I can see is `admin_menu`, so before that comes (listing only useful core hooks, from later to earlier)

- auth_redirect
- update_option
- wp_loaded
- init
- pre_get_posts
- after_setup_theme
- get_template_part
- setup_theme
- plugins_loaded
- muplugins_loaded

What are you trying to do, exactly? the complete answer depends on your use case.

Comment: wp_loaded worked in my case.